# Imageview doesn't update. I've tried to use `invalidate();` but that didn't work

Tags: android, imageview

I'm trying to change the imageview 3 times in a short period of time. 
I want to set the image, have sheldon say "Bazinga", then change imageview directly after he the audio is completed. And then I want to do that a second time. 
Note that the first image is already set before calling this function:

```
sound = MediaPlayer.create(this, R.raw.bazinga);
sound.start();
page.setImageResource(R.drawable.counttotwofirst);
while(sound.isPlaying()){}

sound.start();
page.setImageResource(R.drawable.counttotwosecond);
while(sound.isPlaying()){}
sound.release();

page.setClickable(true);
```

I've tried to use `invalidate();` but that didn't work.

Is there anyway to force update or at least wait until the imageview has been updated?
How long time is there between updates if imageviews?
Is there some other view I should use instead?

Comment: Are you maybe freezing your UI thread?

Comment: imagine that you want to do that not 3 times but 3 billion times in a loop. it would mean that your loop would be executed almoast forever, but what about the rest of your code? it would never execute. do you see now what you are doing wrong?

Comment: Hint: Try using [MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/MediaPlayer.OnCompletionListener.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to re-think the design a bit.  I am guessing you are running all of that code on the main (UI) thread of your app.  The problem is that although you are changing the image resource, you are then causing the UI thread to block (sitting in a while() loop), so the UI updates don't get performed until after your entire function returns.  You probably need some more pieces to achieve the sound/animation effects you want.  Off the top of my head, probably create a background thread for performing the sound loading/playback so that's not done on the UI thread.  Also, instead of sitting in a while() loop until the sound finishes, it's better to have a callback notify you that playback has completed (take a look at MediaPlayer::setOnCompletionListener()).